# I have to use sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))) when using modules in other files?

Tags: python

My current folder structure looks like this -

```
    ├── src/
    │   ├── data/
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── make_dataset.py
    │   │
    │   ├── models/
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── train_model.py
    │   │
    │   └── __init__.py
    │
    └── setup.py
```

but when I'm trying to use the `data` package and the `make_dataset.py` module, I can't use relative imports like `from make_dataset import DataCorpusEncoderManager, DataSplitter` it says make_dataset 'no module found'. When I add this code it works fine but it doesn't seem the right way to do it.

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

from data.make_dataset import DataCorpusEncoderManager, DataSplitter
```

Comment: In which file are you trying to import the module?

Comment: I'm trying to import the module in the train_model.py module

Comment: What is the content of the data/__init__.py file?

Comment: and did you try doing: `from src.data.make_dataset import *`